# React Native- JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "no"

Tags: javascript, php, react-native

- When I filter the products with respect to category and showing products in ViewProducts.js, I am getting this issue.
- When I filter the products with respect to category and only showing in the alert in categiry.js it is showing me all the fetched filtered data in the alert box.
- Whereas when I am not filtering products with respect to the category, it is showing me all the products with no error.

Below is the code for fething in ViewProducts.js

```
  componentDidMount() {
  return fetch('http://192.168.0.109/fyp/products.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
      }, function() {
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    }); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: An example of the JSON content you get when the error occurs would help.

Comment: Yes that would be good. Or you could just check if your response string is a valid JSON

Comment: In alert it is fetching the data while showing it is giving me the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happen if you are having an error and its not json_encoded. 
Try catching all the errors you are receiving and echo Json response
For instance mysql insert error could be handled as below

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    // If the record inserted successfully then show the message.
    $MSG = "New record created successfully";

// Converting the message into JSON format.

    $json = json_encode($MSG);

// Echo the message.
    echo $json;

} else {
    $errorMsg="Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    $json = json_encode($errorMsg);
    echo $json;
}
```

Otherwise you can share your server code, will help troubleshoot!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the response you are getting is not in the proper JSON format,
so before cloning it to list view do console.log or console.warn of 
fetch(URL)then(response)=>response.text() and print here 
then if you are getting JSON means then parse that or else show some snack 
[image]